# Ubuntu Wifi connection Lost

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have just started learning about it. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and had trouble connecting to the network. I found out the following solutions in one of the threads:

1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running sudo lshw -class network
2. Get your card model info according to the product line. For instance, as u can see in the question description it says product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter so the model of my card is RTL8723BE
3. Open or create /etc/pm/config.d/config and add SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"(replace rtl8723be with your own model number) Then run echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf and reboot.

Now your system should be able to reconnect automatically after sleep, and wifi connection never got lost once for me after doing this.

But as I am new, I am unable to perform step three. Can someone please elaborate on what commands do I have to use in order to perform step 3

I went to the directory /etc/pm/config.d --- but there is nothing in it 
No config folder

Comment: Try <code>sudo service network-manager restart</code> , tell if it work or not.

Comment: Tried this. Worked as a temporary solution. After 2 mins the wifi got disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config is a file in this case, directories end with a slash.

An easy way to create this file is to

- open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config` to open/create the file with root permissions (needed anywhere beside /home/* folders)
- Now add `SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"`
- Save the file and close gedit.
- Go back to your terminal and type `echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

That should exactly be what you need to do in Step 3.

P.S.: You don't have to type the commands, you can copy and paste in terminal with the additional use of <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. For instance paste in terminal is: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or copy in terminal is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Have Fun!

Comment: I did all the steps. Thank you. But I am still unable to connect to the wifi

Comment: Even the wifi profiles are also not  visible.

Comment: Not sure what exactly your problem is. Maybe open a new question, paste all information from `sudo lshw -class network` and ask for help. I solved similar problems with setting up an after sleep script which restarts the network manager, but that may not be sufficient in all circumstances.

Comment: Okay will do that .. Now even the Wifi option is not visible.